# Where can I get a typhoid vaccination in Ljubljana?

Tags: health, slovenia, ljubljana

I am from USA. I need a typhoid vaccination to go to Morocco. I am traveling in Ljubljana, Slovenia. Where can I get the injection at? I need the injection, not pills.

Comment: If nobody answers, but you find a solution on your own, feel free to return and post an answer to your own question!

Answer (score 4):

National Institute of Public Health of Slovenia (NIJZ) suggests you can get vaccinated in an [outpatient clinic](http://www.nijz.si/en/outpatient-clinics-nijz-0) in Ljubljana. Here is their information:

> Address: [Zaloška 29, 1000 Ljubljana](https://www.google.si/maps/search/Zalo%C5%A1ka+29/@46.0544995,14.5264544,17z/data=!3m1!4b1)
>
> Phone: 00 386 1 58 639 00

They are open from Monday to Friday, 08:00 - 12:00 (local time, 24h format). You will need an appointment, which you can get via phone (same working hours). This information is from the [Slovenian version](http://www.nijz.si/ambulante#obmocna-enota-ljubljana) of the webpage I previously linked - it is not present in the translated version.

It will set you back 30€ according to the last entry of 1. page [of this document](http://www.nijz.si/sites/www.nijz.si/files/uploaded/cenik_storitev_ambulante_za_cepljenje_velja_od_1_1_2016.pdf) in Slovenian (`typhoid` is referred to as `tifus`).

This is not your only option. There are lots of other clinics that would offer this service for you. The receptionists of the hotel where you are staying would probably be able to help arrange things for you (and would probably send you to the same clinic I list above).

Note: you should get the vaccine 14 days before you travel.